# I want to convert any Language String to English in Java

Tags: java, string, locale

I am reading feed from a hindi site and want to convert it to english.

```
public class ReadTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        RSSFeedParser parser = new RSSFeedParser("http://aajtak.intoday.in.feedsportal.com/c/34152/f/618432/index.rss?option=com_rss&feed=RSS1.0&no_html=1&rsspage=home");
        Feed feed = parser.readFeed();

        System.out.println(feed);
        for (FeedMessage message : feed.getMessages()) {
            System.out.println(message.getTitle());
            System.out.println(message.getDescription());
            System.out.println("Date : " + message.getPublishDate());
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code which i am using but it will print something like below.

```
Feed [copyright=, description=?? ??, language=en, link=http://aajtak.intoday.in, pubDate=Sun, 14 Sep 2014 06:10:50 GMT, title=?? ??]
?? ??
??? ??????? ???? ?? ?? ???? ??????. ??????? ?????? ?????? ?? ?????? ????? ????? ?? ???? ?????? ?????????? ??? ????...
Date : Sun, 14 Sep 2014 05:42:56 GMT
-------------------------
?????? ?? ???? ? ???? ?? ???? ???? ????, ?????-???? ???
????? ???????? ?????? ?? ?????? ??????? ????? ???? ???? ?? ?????? ????? ?????? ?? ?? ????? ?? ???? ?????? ??????...
Date : Sun, 14 Sep 2014 04:56:24 GMT
```

where "?" is getting printed where a hindi character is there.

Comment: Wait, so you want to write code that translates hindi to English, or am I missing something here?  Translating is hard.  And not perfect.

Comment: Yes i want to convert any language to english, here hindi is just one example.

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/steps.html

Comment: A quick search gave that: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/ and that:https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/

Comment: The problem is i don't know the language of incoming text, whichever language it is in i want to convert it to english.

Comment: So the requirement is to convert any text to English regardless (and not knowing) of the input language. Interesting. Basically you thought the next million dollar idea can fit in 10 lines of Java code?

Comment: Its not a million dollar idea its a billion dollar idea Jaya . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current problem has nothing to do with translation (still not ...) but only with *character sets*. If the original feed correctly declares its own charset, Java internally uses [unicode](http://www.unicode.org) characters and can read it.

But I suppose your system uses a character set other than Utf-8 (Latin-1, Win1252, CP-850 or CP437), and cannot display hindi characters. If you use Linux or another Unix-like, ensure you are using UTF-8 ; if you use Windows try to use a graphic windows (Swing) for the output, because I do not know how a command line window (CMD.exe) can handle unicode.

But if you pass that step, translation is another far more complex problem ...